# Compiz Grid feature abruptly stopped working correctly. Now ctrl +alt + num 4 and num 6 only allow half screen tiling

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands)

I've used the Compiz Grid function for a long time and I generally use it to set my browser to the right 2/3 or 3/4 of the screen and have other apps on the top or bottom half of the remaining part. Now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> it only does half and when pressing it a second or third time it does nothing. The options for different sizes work for all the corners and top and bottom. The upper right is also behaving the same as the top option.

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit

I've tried the following commands:

```
unity -reset
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 (followed by another unity -reset)
```

I've deleted `~/.compiz-1` and logged out and in. 
I've disabled and reenabled grid from `ccsm`. (this segfaults unity btw)

I'm afraid to uninstall and reinstall compiz or the grid plugin as it is pretty deeply embeded into Unity and will probably break things.

If anybody has any suggestions or knows what will happen if I uninstall compiz or grid I'd love to know. Otherwise I may reinstall Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: This has been bugging me too.  I've also noticed that Ctrl+Alt+KP9 sends the window to the top-center instead of the top-right as expected.

Comment: Mine did the same thing with ctrl alt kp9. It wasn't like that when I first installed but I suspect the last upgrade

Comment: I did try uninstalling the compiz package via tty and it also uninstalled Unity with it. It was pretty simple to get back. I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: I filed a bug report.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/879218

Comment: Also will be following this one on launchpad.  A "must" to get back!!!

Comment: Bug report reports that this has been fixed since 20/12/11 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/876591

Comment: This is a bug, for more information about the bug please subscribe to the bug report [on LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/879218)