# Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

Using Unity in Ubuntu 12.04, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num Pad</kbd> combination for positioning windows no longer works completely consistently:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (move window to left half of screen) was changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.
- A similar change moved <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

So in 12.04 one moves windows to corners using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combos, but Super combos are needed to move to the left or right.

This is more than a convenience problem since the new windows positioning provided by the super key combos seems to give different sizes than the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combos they replaced, leading to distracting gaps between windows when you combine the two methods to position three or more windows on one screen.

Is there a way to restore the previous behaviour so that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd> Pad for all window positioning?

Comment: Since this isn't necessarily read by People In Charge, you might want to ask explicitly if anyone has a workaround or a way to revert to the old behavior.  Someone else might have a better suggestion for where to actually send this suggestion.

Comment: I restored the functionality with the answers below but one thing is still missing. Windows where resized when repeatedly hitting  control-alt-9 / 3 / 1 / 7 no rezising happens anymore with 4 and 6.

Comment: You are right, resizing is missing.  Perhaps this feature was removed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]. Search for "compiz" in the Unity Dash, or start with `ccsm` from the commandline.

> ### Warning
>
> CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`) is an advanced tool, and not all of its options are completely compatible with Unity.
> As such, [CCSM has been known to sometimes break users'
> desktops](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/18612). Please use caution and
> know that you are taking a risk by following this answer or any other
> answer that recommends the use of CCSM. In the event that following
> this advice does break Unity, please see [this
> question](https://askubuntu.com/q/17610/18612) for instructions on how
> to reset it.

Find the *Grid* plugin:

[image]

Click on the key binding you want to change, click on *Grab key combination,* and press the keys you'd like to use.

[image]

Comment: Thanks allot!  The pictures and apt link are a nice touch.  I had previously tried everything in CCSM _except_ Grid because the name seemed to imply moving windows among workspaces.

Comment: In my case I had already predefined short key for this, but it was different that the others: Ctrl+Super+Left/Right. Super is the Win key it you have that kind of keyboard.
Anyway I had to install compiz to see it. Thanks for the answer and screens!

Answer (score 20):

The shortcuts have been replaced with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>. At the moment, Compiz (Unity's backend) does not support multiple shortcut keys for one action. This may change in the future.

Hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> to see them all:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - really appreciate the informative response and have checked the Ctrl-Super-Left and Right shortcuts work for me. 
This will be fine for the time being although looking at the forums I can see other comments on the same topic and it would be good if a future release did address this

Comment: How would we go about changing the Ctrl + Super + {Left/Right} to make use of the keypad 4 and keypad-6 keys?  This is highly annoying, considering that the keypad owns the majority of the window movement commands, but yet the left and right movements are removed and placed on the arrow keys, requiring the user to lift their right hand off the keypad to go to the arrows.

Comment: see @blackhawkover's answer: change key bindings in ccsm > grid

Comment: My question already states what the new hotkeys are; I am asking how to return them to their former numpad mappings.

Answer (score 6):

I too had this problem.

You'll need to install `compizconfig-settings-manager` (CCSM).

In CompizConfig Settings Manager go to "Grid" (near the bottom under *Window Management*):

[image: ccsm options]

Set the bindings (which was not set for me either) to *Put Left* as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, and *Put Right* as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>:

[image: ccsm - grid options]

I too would like to see this as a standard put into a patch for put window using number pad.

Comment: This is the same answer as given by andrewsomething, but a month later.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to run a command in the command dash?

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in following:

```
unity --reset
```