# Why don't Ctrl-Alt-Numpad6 and Ctrl-Alt-Numpad4 work anymore?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands)

My favourite standard keyboard shortcut when using Ubuntu 11.10 was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 6</kbd> to push a window to the left or right half of the desktop - particularly useful when copying files from the desktop to somewhere on the filesystem using Nautilus.

I note the other Numpad Window Controls seem to have been preserved but not the '6' or '4' sequences.

If this is correct - Can we have them back in a future patch or next release  ?