# Ubuntu 18 activate ctr+alt+num for window placement

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, window-manager, gnome-shell

It seems to be a recurring problem in ubuntu releases that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> for window placement gets deactivated

Ubuntu 14
[How to remap default unity window placement shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510285/how-to-remap-default-unity-window-placement-shortcuts)

Ubuntu 12
[Why don't Ctrl-Alt-Numpad6 and Ctrl-Alt-Numpad4 work anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126563/why-dont-ctrl-alt-numpad6-and-ctrl-alt-numpad4-work-anymore)

What is the trick this time with Ubuntu 18?

Comment: Have you tried CCSM as suggested in the linked questions? It should still work with Unity. If not, what *exactly* did you do and what happened? Are you sure that you use Unity and not Gnome Shell’s “Mutter” which is the new default window manager in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ineed i seem to be running a gnome windows magager, I assume it's "Mutter". The question still remains though: How is Ctrl+Alt+number activated in 'Mutter'

Comment: @DavidFoerster Oh, and yes I did try (various combinations in) the CSSM as in the linked questions. They seem to have no effect on this particular problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04)

Comment: @pomsky So the answer is the 'Put Windows' GNOME extension. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/