# How to make Ctrl-Alt-Num 4 and 6 shortcuts work?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands)

#### [Window Placement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Num 4</kbd> - Place window on the left side of the screen.

<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Num 6</kbd> - Place window on the right side of the screen.

How to make these two shortcuts work.

This [wallpaper](http://ubuntuone.com/p/pBs/) contains these two shortcuts.

Comment: are you on a Desktop or Laptop? For these shortcuts to work, you have to use the number-pad. To simulate a number pad on a Laptop you have to use the FN key to switch to number mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try enabling the "Put" compiz plugin using the CompizConf settings manager. You might need to change the key bindings to match your preferences.