# Can no longer position windows with keyboard (Compiz Grid feature broken)

Tags: 12.04, compiz, keyboard, numpad

**Problem description**
The `compiz grid` feature just stopped working a couple of days ago: for instance I used to be able to move a `terminal` window to the top left corner by pressing `<ctrl><alt>KP7` but now the number `7` appears in the `terminal` and the window doesn't move.

**Troubleshooting**
 -[`compiz grid` is enabled and I have restored its configuration to the default values](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands)
-my `numpad` is working properly (i.e. if it's locked I get the numbers, if not I get `home`, `ins`, `del`... as expected).
-I looked into the `Keyboard` and `Keyboard layout` settings but I don't see any option I could tweak to fix the problem.

**What do I need to do in order to restore the `compiz grid` feature?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out issue was caused by a combination of factors:

- `Compiz` (at least its grid component) requires `Ubuntu 3D desktop` (if you run `$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` inside a terminal and get `ubuntu 2d` it means you're not running the 3d desktop).
- I couldn't run the `3d desktop` because my Nvidia card was not being properly supported with the default drivers (which I solved by installing the [`BumbleBee` drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219721/glx-on-nvidia-optimus-ubuntu-12-04#answer-219750)).