# GLX on NVIDIA Optimus, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia-optimus, minecraft

I have a laptop that has an NVIDIA Optimus graphic card setup. I have tried running Minecraft on that laptop, and the game crashes after login, with the following error:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
```

I tried to update my drivers, but no driver update was available. I searched for people asking the same question and I found none, hence the following question:

*Is it possible to enable GLX on NVIDIA Optimus? If yes, how to?*

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
More information about the graphic card

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1058 (rev a1)

lshw -C video

*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: NVIDIA Corporation
   fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   ressources: irq:16 mémoire:da000000-daffffff mémoire:d0000000-d7ffffff mémoire:d8000000-d9ffffff portE/S:3000(taille=128)
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   fabriquant: Intel Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 2
   information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   ressources: irq:44 mémoire:db000000-db3fffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff portE/S:4000(taille=64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video card based on the Intel chips.
I suggest you refer to Bumblebee project support:

[Ubuntu Wiki: Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)
[Bumblebee project page: Installing Bumblebee 3.0](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html)

Comment: Hadn't even understood Bumblebee's object was to support NVIDIA Optimus ^^ Thank you big time!