# Resize window actions for left and right placement don't work

Tags: 12.04, window-manager

In previous versions of Ubuntu I could press the combination of keys several times (Ctrl+Alt+Num4 or Num6) to re-size window to different width.

Now this functionality doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04. Though it possible to place to left/right/top/bottom corners with different width so left/right placement should work somehow.

How to restore the left/right placement with changing width?

Comment: Since Ubuntu 12.04 the defaults shortcuts has changed, you could do it using Ctrl+Super+arrow. It works for you or is not what you want?

Comment: On my configuration the Ctrl+Super+arrow applied to another actions.

Comment: So you want to change the shortcut or the effect?

Comment: Yes, I want change the shortcuts

Comment: I have been searching in every nook of the system without luck. I don't know where is wrote the launcher for the Ctrl+Alt+Right|Left shortcut, it's not in dconf. Even it doesn't remove/change/show when I use it for another action. I don't know what to do..

Comment: NOTE: You can try with ccsm. I don't like/recommend it but is to only way to make it work. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/116889/62483) that has all the content that you will need.

Comment: I'm using compiz manager, I've setup everything from your link and it doesn't work. I mean I can put window in on the left and right positions but I can't change the width of those windows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7902/discussion-between-megas-and-lucio)