# Compiz grid stopped supporting anything but half screens

Tags: compiz, window-manager, ccsm

I used to be able to use Compiz to tile windows in quadrants or halves of the screen. It has been a long while since that worked but it finally started to bug me enough that I'd like to troubleshoot it. I do have the "edges" set up in CCSM so that the corners should snap to a quarter of the screen:

[image: CompisConfig Settings Manager screenshot]

But when I drag to a corner, I get the highlight showing that the window will snap to a half screen tile, which is what it does. I want to be able to snap to quarter screen tiles.

Based on my edges settings, the top edge should snap to the top left corner but it actually snaps to full screen.

What can I do to get more sizes available in my Compiz grid?

Note: [Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands) and [Compiz Grid feature abruptly stopped working correctly. Now ctrl +alt + num 4 and num 6 only allow half screen tiling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69102/compiz-grid-feature-abruptly-stopped-working-correctly-now-ctrl-alt-num-4-an) are asking a different question about keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Im having the same issue, have you figured out how to get grids working again with compiz or another program?

Comment: Nope. I"m still suffering.